# For loop - continue when condition evaluates to false

Tags: c++

I use CLion to do my homework. This is my code and the strange error I met but i don't know why. I hope someone could tell me why and how to fix it.

```
void findDownCorner(vector<vector<Point> >& squares, Point2f corners[]){
    Point2f top_left=squares[0][0];
    Point2f top_right=squares[0][0];
    Point2f down_left=squares[0][0];
    Point2f down_right=squares[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<squares.size();i++){
        for(int k=0;k<squares[i].size();i++){
            if(squares[i][k].x < top_left.x){
                top_left=squares[i][k];
            }
            if(squares[i][k].y < top_right.y){
                top_right=squares[i][k];
            }
            if(squares[i][k].y > down_left.y){
                down_left=squares[i][k];
            }
            if(squares[i][k].x > down_right.x){
                down_right=squares[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    corners[0]=top_left;
    corners[1]=top_right;
    corners[2]=down_left;
    corners[3]=down_right;
}
```

As you can see, the size of squares is 8 but now `i` equals 8 and the the loop didn't stop.

[image]

Comment: In your second for loop you increment `i` instead of `k`. `for(int k=0;k<squares[i].size();i++){` should be `for(int k=0;k<squares[i].size();k++){`. That is why you are going through lots of `i`.

Comment: You have a typo in the second for loop. Instead of `++i` it needs to be `++k`.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox,omg you are right, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Correct your for loops like below. Good to use bracket to instruct the compiler which part should execute first to avoid side effect.

```
 for(int i=0;i<(squares.size());i++){
    for(int k=0;k<(squares[i].size());k++){
```

Comment: Don't answer this. It will soon be closed as simple typographical question. Now the OP doesn't have the option to delete it.